# Calling specific class functions in a list of multiple class-types

Tags: c#, list, class, inheritance, crash

I'm trying to make a 2D game using C# (with XNA which is irrelevant to the problem). I've made a basic tile class from which all tiles in the game will inherit basic functions from, like how to draw itself onto the screen and such.

What I have is then a list of that base tile class which holds every single other class which inherits from the base class, I.E: Doors, Walls, Floor-tiles etc.

```
    List<TileBase> tileList = new List<TileBase>();

    ...

    tileList.Add(new Door(arguments));
    tileList.Add(new Wall(arguments));
```

The problem comes later when I want to only affect a certain type of class inside that list. For example, the doors have certain functions for Open(), Close() and Toggle().
If I try to simply make a loop which loops through every Door class in my list:

```
    foreach(Door door in tileList)
    {
            door.Toggle();
    }
```

I get an error:

```
    "Unable to cast object of type '...Tiles.Wall' to type '...Tiles.Door'."
```

So basically, I have a list full of different classes. How do I reach the specific functions in a class in a loop without making the program crash as it attempts it on another type of class which doesn't have said functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could investigate the OfType method, it filters based on type:

```
using System.Linq;
```

...

```
foreach(var door in tileList.OfType<Door>())
{
    door.Toggle();
}
```

Comment: @user2499152 Put `using System.Linq;` at the top of your file so that `OfType` will be in scope.

Comment: Splendid! Seems to be working, thanks for the quick response! This will surely come in handy. I'm glad the solution was a simple one as I had a hard time finding any similar problems. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate using base class and then check if the spesific object is instance of the `Door` class. If yes, cast to the `Door` object.

```
foreach(TileBase td in tileList)
{
       if(td is Door)
       {
             ((Door) td).Toggle();
       }
}
```

Comment: This might be (slightly) less efficient than OfType, because it will iterate objects not used.  I assume that @Khan would be interested in performance as it is a game.

Comment: I had tried something similar earlier but for me it didn't work at the time. It seemed I require the parenthesis that you put around td and (Door). So now I have two possible solutions should I ever require something similar in the future! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach(Door door in tileList.where(a=>a is Door))
{
    door.Toggle();
}
```